# xcode iphone ball animation

Tags: iphone, xcode, animation, timer, coordinates

What I want to do is that every ten second a ball is created outside of the screen, and when it is created it move to the center of the screen. How can I do this?

Comment: vous devez vous rendre à chaque question que vous avez déjà demandé et cliquez sur la case à cocher par la réponse la plus appropriée à l'accepter. Aider les gens à obtenir la reconnaissance. Si vous n'avez pas "accepter" les réponses en cochant les gens sont moins susceptibles d'aider. Vous devez augmenter votre "accepter taux« aussi proche que possible de 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view controller set up a UIImageView property for your ball, contruct the ball and make sure its starting location is off the viewable area of the creen and then use an NSTimer which fires every ten seconds which callas a method that animates your ball across the screen to the centre.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    NSTimer *ballTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:10.0  
                                                 target:self 
                                               selector:@selector(moveBall) 
                                               userInfo:nil 
                                                repeats:YES];

    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:ballTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];

    myBall = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyBallImageFile.png"]];
    myBall.center = CGPointMake(320/2, [self randNumBetween:-50:-100]);
    [self.view addSubview:myBall];
}

-(void)moveBall{
    myBall.center = CGPointMake(320/2, [self randNumBetween:-50:-100]);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 animations:^{
        myBall.center = CGPointMake(320/2, 480/2);
    }];
}
```

**----------EDIT------------**

```
- (CGFloat)randNumBetween:(CGFloat) min :(CGFloat) max{
    CGFloat difference = max - min;
    return (((CGFloat) rand()/(CGFloat)RAND_MAX) * difference) + min;
}
```

Comment: I added a function that generates random numbers, please check my edit.

Comment: there is a problem xcode say "incompatible type for argument 2 of 'CGPointMake' How can I solve this ?

Comment: did it work, if so please mark this question as answered? Also, you are welcome.

Comment: Check my edit, its becausause CGPointMake() requires CGFloat not int.

Comment: no it always say the same thing '"incompatible type for argument 2 of 'CGPointMake'

Comment: The code compiles for me, are you getitng a compilor error or is it crashing when you try to run it and then giving you the error in the console window?

Comment: no when I click build and run there is two errors in red incompatible type for argument 2 of 'CGPointMake'

Comment: Well as I said, the code above which I pasted from my xocde window compiles. So check your code carefully against mine and try to find the error.

Comment: now it work but if i make NStimer for one second the image that was moving come back to another position, I don't want that I want that a new start but not the same image .

Comment: thats because the animation duration is set to 5.0 seconds, so it is going out of sync with the timer. Change the animationDuration to 1.0 seconds.

Comment: no I want an animation of 5 second thus the animation is slow but I want that every second a new image start the animation and not always the same that come back and restart

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    myBallImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"ball.png"] retain];
    myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self selector:@selector(addBallToScreen) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [myBallImage release];
    [myTimer invalidate];
}

- (void)addBallToScreen {
    //Create the imageView
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myBallImage];
    imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(1000, 1000);
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView release];

    //Animate the image view
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(50, 50);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: Simply replace imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(1000, 1000) by the random values (using arc4rand, for example)